# How to choose the right site to ask a question?

Tags: discussion, support, questions, site-recommendation

This morning I realized that I do not understand why the MariaDB `mysql.servers` table has a constraint on its `Db` column, and I decided to go ask it to MariaDB community. I gave up after a few moments because I really don't like that website. My personal opinion.

Then I said to myself: *"let's ask on Stack Exchange!"*

It is not a programming question, so Stack Overflow should not be the right place, and I am not sure where else to post this question, because it goes like *"can anybody explain me this?"*

Is there a guideline telling people how to choose the right Stack Exchange website for their question, if any?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Questions about database terminology / concepts](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34/170252) are allowed on our Database Administrators site. Be certain to check out the [FAQ on how to ask a good question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7931/282094) here, and read the [Help on DBA](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help) and their meta's FAQs.

A look at the MariaDB site might help to improve your question:

- https://mariadb.com/kb/en/constraint/
- https://mariadb.org/mariadb-innodb-foreign-key-constraint-errors/

Typing a search into the main search engine for our sites can sometimes help to narrow down your choice, in this case it seems less helpful when the question doesn't appear to have been asked previously:

- Search for: ["MariaDB+constraints+table+MySQL"](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=MariaDB+constraints+table+MySQL)

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I will try to post there and flag this answer as accepted if they don't scold me :-D Just a clarification: I tried to search answers talking about this but didn't find any. Of course the first place I went was MariaDB site, but it didn't help me and as I explained I didn't use their forum because...well...check it out and tell me if you understand how it works. They don't even have a search function...

Comment: I suggested to review the MariaDB site if you wanted help with terminology, or to explain how the information contained on their site isn't helpful to your question. As to searching there it's possible to use a search engine such as Google, or **the MariaDB site's own search** page: https://mariadb.com/kb/search/

Answer (score 3):

> It is not a programming question, so Stack Overflow should not be the right place, and I am not sure where else to post this question, because it goes like "can anybody explain me this?"

That's hard to tell, unless you don't make any efforts to exactly tell what you don't understand.

> Is there a guideline telling people how to choose the right Stack Exchange website for their question, if any?

There's guidance for each SE site given at the specific site Meta sites, but no overall guide map. You have to check each site's help center indiviually.

Comment: [the site list](https://stackexchange.com/sites#name) has a small description of each site which can guide you somewhat. At least it can let you eliminate some sites as "not relevant" and then target others as "possibly relevant". Then you should still check the help section for those. There *is* overlap with some topics, so more than one site might be relevant for a question. In that situation, pick whichever is probably closest to what you need.